# Why 'face_img-mean_face' in eigenfaces Face Recognition?

Tags: computer-vision, pca, image-recognition, eigenvector

What is the purpose of 'face difference' that obtained by subtracting the face image with the mean image?

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the mean from the data is a standard step in performing PCA, which is what eigenfaces does.

Briefly, PCA is an algorithm which projects your data (`face_img`) onto an orthogonal basis. Then it removes the smallest eigenvalues from this basis, and returns the top k eigenvectors associated with those eigenvalues (where k < n, the original dimensionality of your data). Linear Algebra tells us that these top k dimensions are the "best k dimensions" for projecting your data onto a linear subspace. *Best* is defined as "explains the most variance". This is the dimensionality reduction magic of PCA. For more information on PCA, I recommend searching https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Eigenvalues are found using [Spectral Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) of the covariance matrix of your data, `face_img`. Implicit in the definition of a covariance matrix is that the data is *mean-centered*. That is, the mean of the data is subtracted from the data. Hence `face_difference = face_img - mean_face`. Most (if not all) software packages bake this into their PCA functionality, but I'd recommend making sure first.